# Elementary proof: division by integer makes real number smaller.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, divisibility, products

It's been so long since I took discrete math, maybe someone here can help me with what ought to be a straight forward and simple proof.

Effectively I want to show this:

- Let a and b be positive integers where **b>a** and b != 0. *(a/b is a rational number between 0 and 1, non-inclusive).*
- Let k and l be (real?) numbers where k = l(a/b)
- **(Meat of the proof here)**
- Then for any l, k < l.

My discrete book doesn't really get into quite this case, and I don't really know what to search for here to find this type of proof. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need $l>0$ to have the result.

$$l-k=l-l\frac{a}b=l\frac{b-a}b>0$$
as $l$ and $\frac{b-a}b$ are both positive. So, $l>k$.